# Honeycomb webview flickering jittering

Tags: android, webview

My app has a scrollview and a webview inside a LinearLayout.

When the Ads from millenial come in it happens some jittering and some webview parts get white.

I have tried ALL possible parameter combination and nothing works.

Does anyone a better solution or even a explanation?

Notice the blank text in the bottom:
[image: Notice the blank text in the bottom]

Notice 9 10 11 and 11 sections: 
[image: Notice 9 10 11 and 11 sections]

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those having problems with this I have solved it as following -

```
Compatibility.getCompatibility().setWebSettingsCache(webSettings);
```

Make sure to implement a Compatibility layer, since following method doesn't work in SDK_INT < 11.

```
webViewInstance.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: "compatibility layer" can be done as if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)... if device runs API>=7

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem with AdMob, which I solved by adding:
    android:layer="software"
to the AdView in my xml layout

Answer (score 0):

try adding the attribute android:fadingEdge="none" to the ScrollView in your layout.

Comment: Hi schwiz, I have tried that too! Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: interesting gonna star this to keep tabs on the solution. gl

Comment: @Rafeal Sanches now that I think about it, ditch the ScrollView all together WebView has its own scrolling.

Comment: it's a hardware acceleration incompatibility with the webview and some components like progress

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was removing millenial ads. It seems that their animation to bring the ad visible was interfering with the webview stuff.